# Counting and comparing some repeatedly strings appearances between other strings in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have an input like this:

```
{"id": 123, "class": t1, "format": f1, "class-2": t1, ...}  
{"id": 456, "class": t2, "format": f1, ...}  
{"id": 567, "class": t1, "format": f2, "class-2": t2, "class-3": t1, ...}
```

...

I want an output like this:

```
123 = t1  
456 = t2  
567 = t1
```

...
**(567 classification compares how many times t1 appears against t2)**

I am trying *re.search* but without success. It is a huge text file and I have put everything in the same line but I can not count correctly each class appearance between every id to compare.

Comment: `"class-again": t2, "class-again": t1` is not a valid since you're overriding the same key with a different value - only *one* of them will get picked up by any json parser.

Comment: "class-again" repeatedly was just an example, there is no same key with a different value.

Comment: In that case I don't understand what do you mean by: "567 classification compares how many times t1 appears against t2"

Comment: Imagine "class-again" like "class-2" and so on.

Comment: I shouldn't "imagine" or "guess", instead may I suggest that you'll provide a full yet minimal concrete example.

Comment: Ok, I have edited.

Comment: Since this is json you should parse it as json - do not use regex for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want and since you didn't any code this is my attempt using Regex:

```
import re

string = """{"id": 123, "class": t1, "format": f1, "class-again": t1, ...}  
{"id": 456, "class": t2, "format": f1, ...}  
{"id": 567, "class": t1, "format": f2, "class-again": t2, "class-again": t1, ...} """

for id, cl in zip(re.findall('"id": (.+?),', string), 
                  re.findall('"class": (.+?),', string)):
  print('{} = {}'.format(id, cl))
```

Output:

```
123 = t1
456 = t2
567 = t1
```